# Getting export error in my project ( what's the correct way of exporting ? )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native

I am Getting export error in my project .

what's the correct way of exporting ?

And what's the issue with this?

error:

> > The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> URL:
>   http://192.168.43.244:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false
>
> Body:
>   {"from":"E:\reactNative\chat\awsm\camera\icons.js","to":"../assets/512","message":"Unable
>   to resolve module `../assets/512` from
>   `E:\\reactNative\\chat\\awsm\\camera\\icons.js`: could not resolve
>   `E:\reactNative\chat\awsm\assets\512' as a folder: it did not
>   contain a package, nor an index
>   file","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]}
>   processBundleResult
>       BundleDownloader.java:172 access$100
>       BundleDownloader.java:38 execute
>       BundleDownloader.java:108 emitChunk
>       MultipartStreamReader.java:69 readAllParts
>       MultipartStreamReader.java:116 onResponse
>       BundleDownloader.java:96 execute
>       RealCall.java:135 run
>       NamedRunnable.java:32 runWorker
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112 run
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587 run
>       Thread.java:818

index.js

```
const globe = require('./globe-icon.png');
const postit = require('./post-it-icon.png');

export { globe,
postit}
```

icons.js

```
   import { globe,
    postit} from '../assets/512'

    const icons =[
   { name: 'Notes', image: postit },
   { name: 'Earth', image: globe }
 ]

   export { icons }
```

[image: in 512 folder , I have index.js]

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `export` is fine, but the `import` is not correct. You need to specify the source of the import. So:

```
import { globe, postit }
```

should be replaced with

```
import { globe, postit } from './whatever'
```

where `'./whatever'` should be `'.'` if the files are in the same folder.

The docs — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

---

Looks like the relative path to the `../assets/512` folder is wrong.

Comment: Looks like the relative path to the `../assets/512` folder is wrong. Where the `index.js` and the `icons.js` are located relative to the root of the project?

Comment: check image in post

Comment: yes right, its in 512 folder . Also , I have tried 512/index but still the same error though in RN we don't need to do.

Comment: Try to export something simpler than the image from that `index.js` e.g. `const foo = 123; export { foo }`. Try to rename `index.js` to something different and then import the file instead of a folder...

Comment: now getting other error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_icons2.default.map')`

Comment: How are you importing icons.js? If you are importing icons.js like this: import Icons from ‘path/to/icons.js’ then it will fail as it is expecting a default export as your error message is suggesting. Try change export { icons } in icons.js to export default icons;